# Swift - size of textfield on UIAlertcontrller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I want to increase the initial height of UITextField on UIAlertController.
Here is my code:

```
let reportAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Report", message: "If you find anything to report, please write it in the text box below and press send. To cancel report, press cancel.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
reportAlertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (tf) -> Void in
  tf.frame.size.height = 1500
  tf.placeholder = "Report detail(s) here"
})


reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(reportAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The thing is that even I reassign the frame size, it is not reflected in alert. Any help will be appreciated.

Edited:
Or I want to know the way to expand the height as it reaches the end of width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
    let reportAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Report", message: "If you find anything to report, please write it in the text box below and press send. To cancel report, press cancel.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
reportAlertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (tf) -> Void in
  tf.frame.size.height = 1500
  tf.placeholder = "Report detail(s) here"
})


reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(reportAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
reportAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
presentViewController(reportAlertController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
           self.layoutIfNeeded() //Update frame
        })
```

Comment: It was tf.layoutIfNeeded(). Anyway, it is not working.

Comment: `self.layoutIfNeeded()` will layout all subviews of the `UIView` of the current `UIViewController`, it's better to use `self` because it's also this compute with other subviews. So if there is a frame change in another subview this will compute correctly. Huh anyway, you should try it on your `reportAlertController `. And also you should call `self.layoutIfNeeded()` in the completion block of  `presentViewController `

Comment: Strange, could you check with breakpoints if the height of the frame has been changed correctly before `self.layoutIfNeeded()` ?

Comment: Also you haven't add your UITextfield as a subview of your alertController I think the problem come from there

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought too. However, that is the way we should add textfield to alertcontroller... so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: UITextField is a subclass of UIView. And in an AlertController you can add custom view so I think this works by this way