# How can I change the height of UITextField in UIAlertController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have added a `UITextField` in a `UIAlertController`. I want to change the height of the text field. I have tried this way:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Comments", message: "Write your comments here", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField) -> Void in
    var frame: CGRect = textField.frame
    frame.size.height = 100
    textField.frame = frame
    textField.placeholder = "comment"
    print(textField.frame.size.height)
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
}

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
}

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's not working.

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37470191/4056108)

Comment: already tried, not worked :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works with a **constraint**.

```
alertController.addTextField { textField in
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    textField.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

[image: result of adding the constraint]

Comment: is there also a way to "hide" one text field? Simply setting its height constraint to 0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

@the4kman gave the correct answer, but you can add constraints easier by using the height anchor:

```
textField.addConstraint(textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100))
```