# How to set the height of UITextField in the UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I know that to set the height of regular textfield programatically by using this code

```
textField.frame.size.height = 60
```

But if I implement this code to textfield inside my `UIAlertController`, it doesn't work. I also try to change the keyboard to ASCII capable, but it doesn't change the keyboard after I run the app. it seems I miss something

Here is the code of my alert controller

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Write Comment", message: "Tell us why you are not satisfied", preferredStyle: .alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
    let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
    textField.frame.size.height = 60
    textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable

    let commentDefect = textField.text ?? ""
    self.sendComment(defectID: defectID, comment: commentDefect)

}))

alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 129/255, blue: 58/255, alpha: 1)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = ""
})

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and here is the result :
[image]

It seems the height is still around 17. What went wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171757/how-can-i-change-the-height-of-uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-in-swift here is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have add below code:-

```
alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 120)
        textField.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
})
```

Hope it help you.

It's duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Write Comment", message: "Tell us why you are not satisfied", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in

            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: yourHeightValue)
            textField.placeholder = ""
            textField.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
            textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        }
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in

            let commentDefect = alertController.textFields?.first?.text ?? ""
            self.sendComment(defectID: defectID, comment: commentDefect)
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 129.9/255.0, blue: 58.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```